# Why doesn't it display 10 numbers in the first line?

Tags: python

```
count=0
num=1
while True:
    num+=1
    if count!=100:
        if count in [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90]:
            if isPrime(num) and ispalindrome(num) ==True:
                count+=1
                print("%-6d"%(num))
        else:
            if isPrime(num) and ispalindrome(num) ==True:
                count+=1
                print("%-6d"%(num),end="")
    else:
        break
```

the output is:

```
2     3     5     7     11    101   131   151   181   191   313   
353   373   383   727   757   787   797   919   929   10301 
10501 10601 11311 11411 12421 12721 12821 13331 13831 13931 
14341 14741 15451 15551 16061 16361 16561 16661 17471 17971 
18181 18481 19391 19891 19991 30103 30203 30403 30703 30803 
31013 31513 32323 32423 33533 34543 34843 35053 35153 35353 
35753 36263 36563 37273 37573 38083 38183 38783 39293 70207 
70507 70607 71317 71917 72227 72727 73037 73237 73637 74047 
74747 75557 76367 76667 77377 77477 77977 78487 78787 78887 
79397 79697 79997 90709 91019 93139 93239 93739 94049
```

In the first line it shows 11 numbers.
But in the next line it shows 10 numbers, which is what I need.

Comment: Try running the program with a pen and paper

Comment: Side note: `== True` is unnecessary.

Comment: Basically, it's because you print the Nth item before handling the newline.  Your first line contains items 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 9, 10.  That's a set of 11 items.

Comment: `count` probably starts at zero, but you just print a value with no line ending for that. And then you print another value for every count less than 10, and then finally you print a value followed by a line ending for `count == 10` - so that's eleven values printed. Either initialise `count` to 1, or print the line ending before the value.

Comment: Think carefully about the logic. What is the value of `count` *when it is tested*? Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: Because you are testing count before you increment when you should be incrementing it before testing.

Answer (score 2):

`count` means that the which nth number is going to be found so count start from 1 : `count = 1`

```
count = 1
num = 1
while count != 100:
    num += 1
    if count in [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]:
        if isPrime(num) and ispalindrome(num):
            count += 1
            print("%-6d" % (num))
    else:
        if isPrime(num) and ispalindrome(num):
            count += 1
            print("%-6d" % (num), end="")
```